# html form INSERT INTO database

Tags: php, sql, forms, post, insert

It may be a minor error but I am currently trying to post from a html form into the database to add a new entry.

Here is the code:

```
<div>
  <?php
  $menu = "INSERT INTO content (id, path, name)
  **VALUES ('".$_POST['id']."', '".$_POST['path']."', '".$_POST['name']."')";**

if ($connnect->query($menu) === TRUE) {
    echo "New page added successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error";
}
  ?>

  <form action="" method="post" name="menus" id="menus">
    <table style="width: 500px;">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <textarea name="id" id="id"></textarea>
          </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>
            <textarea name="path" id="path"></textarea>
          </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>
            <textarea name="name" id="name"></textarea>
          </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Upload">
          </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>
 </div>
```

However obviously you cannot put each $_POST from the form into each value is there another way to do this or can someone help me?

Kind Regards,
Lewis

Comment: As you will see by the ** line ** this is where I am referring to the issue

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the query except that it is open to SQL injection. I am not sure what exactly is the issue here. What exactly do you mean by: `obviously you cannot put each $_POST from the form into each value` ?

Comment: And what exactly is the problem? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Also, are you sure it is `$connnect->query` and not `$connect->query` ? (an extra n)

Comment: You should take a look into [PHP Data Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) and make this a more secure script. And why _"obviously you cannot put each $_POST from the form into each value"_?

Comment: @Maximus2012 I know this thankyou I am just creating basics at the moment

Comment: @Maximus2012 also thankyou, it was the connect aha thanks so much

Comment: @sidyll thankyou for the link I will take a look now :)

Answer (score 0):

use sprintf which can make it a bit more readable in the order of the parameters passed to the values:

```
$menu = sprintf("INSERT INTO content (id, path, name) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s')", mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']), mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['path']), mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']));
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering this is your full code, one major problem is that you are inserting the form contents every time the page is loaded. If your form processing is in the same page, you may want to add a simple check. For example:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    # form information received, process it
}

# else continue with your normal script and display the form
?>
```

In this case, in a first page load the `$_POST` data is not set so only the form will apear. When the form is submitted though, the script will detect there is data and process it.

And explained in the comments, [PHP Data Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (or PDO for short) is a much more modern, portable and safe way to deal with databases. There are plenty of explanations over the internet on how and why; and the manual page itself is pretty straight forward to read. You can prepare statements, and then the class itself will handle all the escaping needed to make your script secure. Quick example:

```
# make a connection
$db = new PDO(/* database info */);
# prepare your statement with the placeholders for your data
$st = $db->prepare("
    INSERT INTO content (id, path, name)
         VALUES (?,?,?)
");
# execute the query with the POST data
$success = $st->execute([
    $_POST['id'],
    $_POST['path'],
    $_POST['name']
]);

if (!$success) {
    # error ...
}
```